# I m a math noobie, wondering why algebra work so is my explanation acceptable as casual explanation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If so, then we can reason on why does algebra work? What is the essence of algebra, on meta level what is the procecure that takes place and why do we end up to correct answer for corresponding x.

Actually i think i figured out the 8=x^2+2-(5/8); it works because we want to find out what x is, so we substract the excess -(2-(5/8)), and we are left with value of x^2, which is 6+(5/8), thus we find out the x, by undoing the squaring, thus we take the square root of 6+(5/8), to get the value of x.

E.g. 3=x-3, because we have subtracted 3 from x, and gotten 3, thus the x>3,we add 3 to 3, same applies here with why we add 5/8 to 8. x^2+2>8

5/8+8=x^2+2, to get x^2, we have to substract +2, because we want to be left with 5/8+6=x^2 and x^2+2, is still +2 bigger.

I Think the person who invented algebra was a effing genius. It's hard to catch his train of thought.

Summary: By doing the same operation on both sides we hold the equality of the equation, it's about eliminating the terms with inverse operations to omit to be left with equal value of the variable we want to find out; value = x. Also this can be represented as function.

PS. Someone told me i m blabbering nonsense? Am i?

Comment: Yes, the key idea of elementary algebra is using known quantities to determine unknown ones via the permitted operations (in higher level algebra, these operations often don't bear any resemblance to the usual four, though!) in such a way that you end up with the unknown on one side of an equation and an expression involving the known quantities on the other. This is what the equality symbol is for, largely: it defines quantities on either side of it in terms of the other. I don't know where you got the idea that functions necessarily involve two variables though, because that's not correct

Comment: Ah you are right you can have function such f(x)=2x, what i did mean is that its same as y=2x, as having two variables.

Answer (score 1):

"Doing the same to both sides" of an equation is a useful thing to get into your head. Another you will learn is "be careful not to divide by zero" (an algebraic expression can be equal to zero without you realising it).

Algebra in terms of giving an unknown quantity a name so you can talk about it and manipulate it is a foundational idea for sure.

But that works because numbers behave in regular ways: addition is commutative and associative (which means you can change the order in which you do things - take care with negatives). Also each number has an additive inverse (so you can add it to its negative and get zero). We say that numbers form an abelian group under addition.

Multiplication is a little more complicated - zero does not have a multiplicative inverse, and if you are dealing with integers, only $1$ and $-1$ have multiplicative inverses. You can repair this by working with rational numbers (rational numbers are just fractions: it starts to matter what you mean by a number). But multiplication is still commutative and associative - so, with due care, you can change the order of operations.

Multiplication and addition are also related by the distributive law, which is the one we use when we multiply brackets together.

So we say that the numbers form a Ring (if we don't add the multiplicative inverses) or a Field (if we do).

It is these properties of numbers (and others like taking square roots) which mean that the algebra you are doing works. Changing the order of operations - cancelling by division or by the equivalent of adding the negative of a term to both sides, expanding brackets (or putting brackets in).

In more advanced and abstract work the study turns to the consequences of the properties. We find that there are different systems of numbers - Integers, Rational Numbers, Real Numbers, Complex Numbers, Algebraic Numbers which all have the same core properties - but they may have convenient additional properties: like "every polynomial in one variable with complex number coefficients has a root" (a root is what you might call a solution). The Real Numbers are a Complete Ordered Field (complete is a precise sense in which there are no gaps and ordered means we can say which of two distinct numbers is larger).

I have tried to be clear, but appreciate that there may be a lot of unfamiliar words here.

Comment: if you are dealing with integers, only 1 and −1 have multiplicative inverse? Isn't 2*2^-1=1? Oh, i got it 2^-1=1/2. Should i start to learn about rings and fields next? Do you have general rules/plan how to start building deep understanding of math, i mean to understand math on meta level and not just to be able to do right evaluations? I Wish to develop my math skill as i would be able to comprehend it as native language.

Comment: @ski0 I don't know where you are in learning about these things - if you have just encountered algebra, probably the thing to do is to get used to manipulating algebraic expressions, which you will have to do all the time. Rings and fields are interesting, but move into areas where different questions are to the fore.

Notice how you are using the various rules/properties of numbers, and look up things like this "proof" that $0=1$ https://math.hmc.edu/funfacts/one-equals-zero/

Learn to recognise patterns like $(x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2$.